# How to convert Fuzzy date as Date field in SQL and VB.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, date

I have a duedate field on a table which the datatype is Fuzzydate. How to convert this to Date field in SQL and VB?

For example the Duedate on backend is : Duedate = 20160531 and I wan to convert it as Duedate = 2016-05-31

Comment: See explanation and examples here: http://www.blackbus.org/Forums/tabid/63/aft/40438/Default.aspx

Comment: I'm not clear on your situation.  Is 20160531 stored as an nchar(8) or Int datatype.  What data type do you want to convert it to (a .Net String or .Net DateTime)?  Where do you want the conversion to take place (before you retrieve it or in your VB code)?

Comment: Fuzzydate isn't a real typename in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

If this is always in the exact format you specified then you can use DateTime.ParseExact:

```
dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact("20160531", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If it is in a number of different formats, you can use TryParseExact a number of times with different formats or just:

```
CDate()
```

Then to convert it to whatever date format you need:

```
dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```